# How to find out that a TreeSet contains a complex object with implicit field value

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I have a simple class Trainee:

```
public class Trainee {
private String firstName, lastName;
private int grade;

// constructors, getters-setters, etc.
```

And I need to write a method that is looking for a Trainee with the same name and a different last name in `TreeSet<Trainee>`. My first attempt was just iterate TreeSet with for-each and then simple if-construction, returning true/false, but my teacher said that checking each element in TreeSet is not a good idea. I really don't know how to solve this. Meh.

Comment: Hint: elements of a tree are ordered.  Searches can be done in log(n) time.

Comment: If I have compareTo() method which compares firstName and then lastName, ceiling() method could be a solution?

Comment: What do you need to have returned? A boolean that will say if other trainee with same firstName exists in the set or other trainees with same firstName?

Comment: A boolean. I already gave possible answer for myself, will wait till he checks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean findWithAnotherLastName(TreeSet<Trainee> trs, Trainee someone) {
    Trainee lower = trs.lower(someone);
    Trainee higher = trs.higher(someone);
    if (lower != null && lower.getFirstName().equals(someone.getFirstName())) {
        return true;
    }
    return higher != null && higher.getFirstName().equals(someone.getFirstName());
}
```

I hope this is the answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention that `Trainee` implements `Comparable`

Answer (score 0):

Override Object.equals() method in Trainee class.

```
public boolean equals (Object o)  
{
   return this.firstName.equals(((Trainee)o).getFirstName());  
}
```

And call `set.contains(obj)` to check if Object is present in Set or not.